# How to import the Spring Data examples into STS

Tags: spring-data

I downloaded the example code from [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples), but when I imported the project into STS, there are many errors. Why is it happening? How to solve the problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Data examples use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and thus need it installed into your IDE to make the code compile.

There already a [ticket filed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/192) to mention this more prominently in the README.